# Creating administrator account programmatically Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have been struggling to create administrators' account using upgradeDataScripts in Magento2 but in vain. I have tried to use the same procedures as used in the command-lines as well as MySQL insert statements to insert the admninistrators in the admin_user table. 
When using the MySql insert statement, the passwords have not been encrypted correctly and thus, logging using the created accounts have failed.

I had also tried using the userFactory but i kept getting setAreaCode error despite having tried all the proposed solution on the web to correct the issue.

Can someone please tell me what is the correct way to implement the above requirements?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 has provided a CLI command for implementing admin user creation.

From your magento root dir, you can run command-

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="A"--admin-email="{{your_email}}" --admin-password="admin#123"
```

If you want to do same thing from code..you can use php's [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) method

Comment: Yes this is working but unfortunately I have been asked not to use the exec command.